# Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent on Android Studio 3.3 Canary 3 Kotlin project

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, kotlin

I just created a new project on Android Studio 3.3 Canary 3 with Kotlin enabled. Then I also enabled data binding, but I'm getting an error saying that it could not find the DataBindingComponent class.

Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
    addRepos(repositories)
    dependencies {
        classpath deps.android_gradle_plugin
        classpath deps.kotlin.plugin
        classpath deps.kotlin.allopen
        classpath deps.navigation.safe_args_plugin
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}

allprojects {
    addRepos(repositories)
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My module gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'


    android {
        compileSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
        buildToolsVersion build_versions.build_tools
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "arca.advanced.mg.com.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
            targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation deps.support.app_compat
        implementation deps.support.recyclerview
        implementation deps.support.cardview
        implementation deps.support.design
        implementation deps.support.legacy
        implementation deps.navigation.fragment_ktx
        implementation deps.room.runtime
        implementation deps.lifecycle.runtime
        implementation deps.lifecycle.extensions
        implementation deps.lifecycle.java8
        implementation deps.retrofit.runtime
        implementation deps.retrofit.gson
        implementation deps.glide.runtime

        implementation deps.dagger.runtime
        implementation deps.dagger.android
        implementation deps.dagger.android_support
        implementation deps.constraint_layout
        implementation deps.kotlin.stdlib

        implementation deps.timber
        implementation deps.rx.java
        implementation deps.rx.android

        kapt deps.dagger.android_support_compiler
        kapt deps.dagger.compiler
        kapt deps.room.compiler
        kapt deps.lifecycle.compiler
    }
```

my fragment file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="arca.advanced.mg.com.arca.ui.splash.SplashViewModel" />

    </data>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

and here is my error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's kapt conflict.

Try to turn off Dagger if it's possible and check errors from Room like this:

```
Fields annotated with @Relation cannot be constructor parameters. These values are fetched after the object is constructed.

Cannot find setter for field.

Cannot figure out how to save this field into database.
```

If it will not help, try to turn off libs with kapt's one by one and check the error log carefully.

Check with `./gradlew app:dependencies` transitive dependencies, maybe problems with androidx.

Also check `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration kapt` maybe you will find something suspicious